# Firebase library wouldn't work with '@grpc/grpc-js' in Next.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm developing the web application in Next.js + Firebase. The problem is that the GRPC in Firebase is called incorrectly, so we need to edit the `node_modules` directly.

It works if I edit the GRPS in `node_modules`, but this is unsound.

Would you help me fix this issue?

> SyntaxError: The requested module '@grpc/grpc-js' is expected to be of type CommonJS, which does not support named exports. CommonJS modules can be imported by importing the default export.
> For example:
> import pkg from '@grpc/grpc-js';
> const { credentials, loadPackageDefinition, Metadata } = pkg;

- package.json

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.27.1",
    "firebase": "^9.6.0",
    "next": "12.0.4",
    "postcss": "^8.4.4",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19"
  },
...
```

Comment: Can you share which NodeJS version worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

upgrade/downgrade version node