# grpc error in nextjs and firebase project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I am working on a Next.js project that uses Firebase. I'm trying to make a simple query with Firestore and I'm getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: The requested module '@grpc/grpc-js' is expected to be of type CommonJS, which does not support named exports. CommonJS modules can be imported by importing the default export.
For example:
import pkg from '@grpc/grpc-js';
const { credentials, loadPackageDefinition, Metadata } = pkg;
```

It seems like [Firebase library wouldn't work with '@grpc/grpc-js' in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70232606/firebase-library-wouldnt-work-with-grpc-grpc-js-in-next-js) asks the same question, but I'm not sure what Node version to upgrade or downgrade to.

Comment: you can either upgrade or downgrade node version .

Comment: What version of Node.js are you currently on?

Comment: Currently ```v12.18.3``` when running `node -v`